# Export to Excel From DB is too slow

Tags: c#, performance, excel

My function works pretty slowly with big results from the db (420000 records and growing). Can some one give me any proposal to make it faster?

```
 public void GenerateExcelFileWithSPResultData(IEnumerable<Plans_Result> datasource, string excelFile)
    {

        var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage();
        ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Plans");


        ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "ACC_DATE";
        ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = "DUE_DATE";
        ws.Cells[1, 3].Value = "IDENTIFIER_VALUE";
        ws.Cells[1, 4].Value = "INSTALLMENT_NO";
        ws.Cells[1, 5].Value = "PRINCIPAL_AMT_DUE";
        ws.Cells[1, 6].Value = "SPA";

        for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
        {
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).ACC_DATE;
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).DUE_DATE;
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).IDENTIFIER_VALUE;
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).INSTALLMENT_NO;
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).PRINCIPAL_AMT_DUE;
            ws.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = datasource.ElementAt(i).SPA;
        }

        using (ExcelRange rng = ws.Cells["A1:F1"])
        {
            rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            rng.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
            rng.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
            rng.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(Color.Black);
        }
        byte[] data = excelPackage.GetAsByteArray();

        File.WriteAllBytes(excelFile, data);
    }
```

Comment: I can recommend taking a look at Excel-OleDb and read/write excel sheets as if they were databases... this is super fast if you don't necessariliy have to do other things.

Comment: If you're getting your data in a `DataTable`, you can export it to `xml`.  Excel can import `xml` directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't use the suggestions in the comments by t3chb0t or tinstaafl, you could maybe use the **[Open XML SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk)**.

In your current code it is rather inefficient that you are calling `datasource.ElementAt(i)...` for each property on the same data element. Depending on how `ElementAt(i)` is implemented, it can be a considerable bottleneck, to search for the same element each time calling `ElementAt(i)`.

The solution is obviously to create a temporary `Plans_Result`-reference for each loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < datasource.Count(); i++)
{
  Plans_result item = datasource.ElementAt(i) as Plans_result;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 1].Value = item.ACC_DATE;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 2].Value = item.DUE_DATE;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 3].Value = item.IDENTIFIER_VALUE;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 4].Value = item.INSTALLMENT_NO;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 5].Value = item.PRINCIPAL_AMT_DUE;
  ws.Cells[i + 2, 6].Value = item.SPA;
}
```

Alternatively you could use a `foreach-statement` while counting the rows in a separate index variable:

```
int index = 2;
foreach (Plans_result item in datasource)
{
  ws.Cells[index, 1].Value = item.ACC_DATE;
  ...
  index++;
}
```

I would use the latter as it is more efficient, because `ElementAt(i)` may be rather slow for large vectors.

Comment: Oh yea, `ElementAt` is really bad here... unless the source is an `IList` then it wouldn't be so bad but still not optimal. However, in order to avoid the helper index I would use `.Select((planResult, index) => (planResult, index: index + 2))` and return a tuple.

Comment: @Henrik Hansen you suggestion really help me. Now i export my result less then 30 sec.

Comment: @t3chb0t: You can do that, but you are not avoiding the index. In fact you are creating `n` indices and tuples (where `n == datasource.GetCount()`). I don't see any benefit in that. :-)

Comment: the benefit is simplicity ;-]